# Datatables file size sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

So I am trying to implement Datatables sorting for file sizes in our app. I am having trouble trying to use the file-size plug in that DT provides.  Here is how I am trying to implement in but I am getting the following error (attached). Thanks in advance. It's the "columns" line where I've tried to implement it. ax.Utils.fileSizeString is a utility in the app - nothing to do with this problem.

My code that's not working.

```
   orderAttachmentsDTO[orderItemID] = $attachmentsTable.DataTable({
          destroy:true,
          data:itemAttachments,
          columns:[orderAttachmentsMap,{ "type": "file-size", "targets": 2 }],
          autoWidth:false,
          order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
          paging:false,
          dom:'ft',
          searching: false,
          language: {
            emptyTable: ax.L(911),
            zeroRecords: ax.L(911)
          }
        });

      //here's the code for the row
      {title:ax.L(713), class:'size', data:function(row, type, val, meta) {
    if (row.file) { return ax.Utils.fileSizeString(row.file.size); }
```

[image]

I get the error attached when try to open that table.

[image]

this is what the table looks like ( the code is insanely long to post here due to all of the html that DT injects)
Below is the json response with the "file" node.

```
1:{attachment_type_display_name: "File", attachment_type_id: 1, 
attachment_type_name: "file",…}
attachment_type_display_name:"File"
attachment_type_id:1
attachment_type_name:"file"
comment:""
creation_time:"2018-03-23T11:41:14-05:00"
creation_time_ms:"1521823274.000"
creation_user_profile_display_name:"Josh"
creation_user_profile_first_name:"Joshua"
creation_user_profile_id:260
creation_user_profile_last_name:"Siegal"
external_key:null
file:{base_filename: "test", checksum: "799498d1d0b799e06b10d2334a313681",…}
base_filename:"test"
checksum:"799498d1d0b799e06b10d2334a313681"
creation_time:"2018-03-12T14:29:45-05:00"
creation_time_ms:"1520882985.000"
creation_user_profile_display_name:"Josh"
creation_user_profile_first_name:"Joshua"
creation_user_profile_id:260
creation_user_profile_last_name:"Siegal"
exclude_from_purge:0
file_extension:"xlsx"
file_root_id:16
file_type_display_name:"Microsoft Office - OOXML - Spreadsheet"
file_type_id:345
file_type_mime_type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
file_type_name:"xlsx"
has_preview:0
id:4524
last_modified_time:"2018-03-12T14:29:45-05:00"
last_modified_time_ms:"1520882985.000"
last_modified_user_profile_display_name:"Josh"
last_modified_user_profile_first_name:"Joshua"
last_modified_user_profile_id:260
last_modified_user_profile_last_name:"Siegal"
object_deleted:null
object_deleted_time:null
object_deleted_time_ms:null
preview_file_extension:null
preview_file_root_id:null
size:26421
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your input data please?
Looks like a column or index issue

Comment: @yuri will get that for you

Comment: As @Yuri said, the input data is likely to be the cause. That error is normally caused when the input data isn't in the expected format, for example if you have an array of objects. If that is the case, you would need to define the columns when you initialise the table.

Comment: @Yuri did you just want the JSON response?

Comment: Yes, just `console.log(itemAttachments );` and show the output log.

Comment: @Yuri added. Thank you.

Comment: Please, copy and paste it, do not take a screenshot.. We would not be able to test your code with the same input.. (I cannot even see the necessary fields for the table)

Comment: @Yuri edited, hope that works. thanks

Comment: That is not the full content, you could clean it and keep the relevant data.. Please show the column definitions in `orderAttachmentsMap`. 
At this time, it would be easier if you can reproduce a fiddle showing your issue, or at least, where you put your full code since you did not show it all here..